# Android AutocompleteTextview Inline predictions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement a AutocompleteTextview very similar to the Autocomplete of google  in my Android app.

I got all the predictions working but I still miss one feature. I want that the first prediction of the dropdown will be displayed in the EditText of the AutocompleteTextview. Also I want that the item is selected when the user clicks on return (or Tab) like google does it in the browser.

Is there a way to do this with the AutocompleteTextview of Android?

Comment: Do you use a custom Adapter implementation, including the filtering of results?

Comment: Yeah. the filtering is not the problem. It works already. I just want to display the first item of the Popup directly as a hint in the Edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot figure out a way to get the current suggestions list from "outside" the `Adapter` extension, I'd do the following:

**Disclaimer**: I've never tried something like this nor I have the resources to try it right now, angry boss danger.

Assuming you are extending an `Adapter` which has an inner filter that makes the filtering process, you should have overriden the `publishResults()` method. My tip is: declare a class-wide variable of type `String` that when `publishResults()` is called, also sets it to the first of the `FilterResults` strings:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint, final FilterResults results) {
  currentObjects = (List<T>) results.values;
  
  if (results.count > 0) {
    myFirstSuggestion = currentObjects.toString();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  else
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

Additionally, make a new method called `getFirstSuggestion()` that would return this `myFirstSuggestion` string.

So now: how to trigger it? Seems that `AutoCompleteTextView` already has this listener implemented:

> onFilterComplete(int count)
>
> Notifies the end of a filtering operation.

So basically the steps to go would be:

1. Declare this listener over your `AutoCompleteTextView`
2. Inside, use the following shippet to get the first suggestion:

   ```
   AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.your_actv_id);
   ListAdapter adapter = actv.getAdapter();
   String firstSuggestion = adapter.getFirstSuggestion();
   ```
3. `actv.setHint(firstSuggestion);`

For your second question, you'd need to override the `onEditorAction` method, something like this

```
actv.OnEditorActionListener enter = new actv.OnEditorActionListener() {
  public boolean onEditorAction(AutoCompleteTextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
      ListAdapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
      String firstSuggestion = adapter.getFirstSuggestion();
      view.setHint(firstSuggestion);
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

The disclaimer is valid for this latter too, probably if my former idea works, this will also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the first item of the Adapter now. Unfortunately setting the Hint isn't really what I want to do. I want that when a user Inputs "Stack ov" this string should be printed normally and "erflow" should be displayed afterwards. Like for example www .freeimagehosting .net /t/5irzc.jpg

Comment: Yes, sure, I forgot that `setHint()` just works when there's no text in it. In that case you'll probably have to combine it with a `TextWatcher`, so each time an user types a letter, the `onTextChanged()` method will be fired, and there's where you'll have to implement your logic, probably with `setText()` mixed with `yourEditText.setSelection(position)`, where position is the position where to set the cursor at `yourEditText`.

Comment: I am currently immlementing this. I got a problem, that when I call setText the Adapter filters again which results in an endless loop. I can't believe that there is not an easy way to do this? Another approach would be to make an Input-Filter. But this filter would get fired when the user types something in and at this point the adapter doesn't have the appropriate values already. Yet another approach would be to override the drawing Methods. but i am not sure which of this is the best way. What would you say?

Comment: Another way would be "temporarily" disable the filtering, i.e., before the `setText()` statement use the `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` and `setFocusable(false)`, set the text, and call both the above with `true` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use Textwatcher

```
eds.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: What do you mean? To detect any keystroke and fill the EditText with the first element of the list? This causes the cursor to jump around and it is not possible to continue writing easily.